# DnD starter kits and buying equipment

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation

The rules of 5e say that I can use my gp to buy gear instead of the class starter kit. In that case, does that mean that I can use both weapons from the starter kit and weapons that I buy? Or do I have to give up the entire kit to start buying new gear?

For example, if I want to use the Rogue starter kit AND buy a blowgun and darts for 11 gp, would that be cheating?

Comment: I edited to fix the tags and removed your second question; questions are meant to be individual, and your second question has already been asked [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/53549/15469).

Comment: Okay. Next time I'll ask one question per post. Thanks for telling me.

Comment: Hey, don't worry about it. The Stack takes some getting used to.